# Excel - How to create simple filter using VBA ActiveSheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and would like to create a filter based on certain criteria.

I've followed this tutorial

https://trumpexcel.com/vba-autofilter/

Use the sample file given

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcj2r1xn1iriql8/VBA%20Autofilter.xlsm?dl=0

[image]

Copy the following code to VBA Module1 to filter Printer

```
Sub FilterRows()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Printer"
End Sub
```

It works.

Instead of using `Worksheets`, is it possible to implement this code using `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: Works for me. Does the macro run at all? Does any VBA run? If you do a simple sub with just `MsgBox "hello"` , does that work?

Comment: Hmm .. that's weird. It's working now. Thanks for your response. Appreciate it

Comment: @ChristoferWeber, instead of using `Worksheets`, is it possible to implement this code using `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: You should be able to run it with `ActiveSheet` instead. The problem is that the code will then try to change the currently selected sheet, which might be the "wrong" sheet, and might cause issues.

Comment: @user11392987,, it's not a good question to ask since you got code is working,, and when you are thinking to test another method, you must use and test before putting the issue on board !!